# How to get cancellation state for multiple DispatchWorkItems

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

### Background

I'm implementing a search. Each search query results in one DispatchWorkItem which is then queued for execution. As the user can trigger a new search faster than the previous one can be completed, I'd like to cancel the previous one as soon as I receive a new one.

This is my current setup:

```
var currentSearchJob: DispatchWorkItem?
let searchJobQueue = DispatchQueue(label: QUEUE_KEY)

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    let queryString = searchController.searchBar.text?.lowercased() ?? ""

    // if there is already an (older) search job running, cancel it
    currentSearchJob?.cancel()

    // create a new search job
    currentSearchJob = DispatchWorkItem() {
        self.filter(queryString: queryString)
    }

    // start the new job
    searchJobQueue.async(execute: currentSearchJob!)
}
```

### Problem

I understand that `dispatchWorkItem.cancel()` doesn't kill the running task immediately. Instead, I need to check for `dispatchWorkItem.isCancelled` manually. But how do I get the right `dispatchWorkItem`object in this case?

If I were setting `currentSearchJob` only once, I could simply access that attribute like done [in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38372384/1665966). However, this isn't applicable here, because the attribute will be overriden before the `filter()` method will be finished. **How do I know which instance is actually running the code in which I want to check for `dispatchWorkItem.isCancelled`?**

Ideally, I'd like to provide the newly-created `DispatchWorkItem` as an additional parameter to the `filter()` method. But that's not possible, because I'll get a `Variable used within its own initial value` error.

I'm new to Swift, so I hope I'm just missing something. Any help is appreciated very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is how to have a dispatched task check if it has been canceled. I'd actually suggest consider [`OperationQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue) approach, rather than using dispatch queues directly.

There are at least two approaches:

- Most elegant, IMHO, is to just subclass [`Operation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation), passing whatever you want to it in the `init` method, and performing the work in the [`main`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1407732-main) method:

  ```
   class SearchOperation: Operation {
       private var queryString: String

       init(queryString: String) { 
           self.queryString = queryString
           super.init()
       }

       override func main() {
           // do something synchronous, periodically checking `isCancelled`
           // e.g., for illustrative purposes

           print("starting \(queryString)")
           for i in 0 ... 10 {
               if isCancelled { print("canceled \(queryString)"); return }
               print("  \(queryString): \(i)")
               heavyWork()
           }
           print("finished \(queryString)")
       }

       func heavyWork() {
           Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.5)
       }
   }
  ```

  Because that's in an [`Operation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation) subclass, [`isCancelled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1408418-iscancelled) is implicitly referencing itself rather than some ivar, avoiding any confusion about what it's checking. And your "start a new query" code can just say "cancel anything currently on the the relevant operation queue and add a new operation onto that queue":

  ```
   private var searchQueue: OperationQueue = {
       let queue = OperationQueue()
       // queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1  // make it serial if you want
       queue.name = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + ".backgroundQueue"
       return queue
   }()

   func performSearch(for queryString: String) {
       searchQueue.cancelAllOperations()
       let operation = SearchOperation(queryString: queryString)
       searchQueue.addOperation(operation)
   }
  ```

  I recommend this approach as you end up with a small cohesive object, the operation, that nicely encapsulates a block of work that you want to do, in the spirit of the Single Responsibility Principle.
- While the following is less elegant, technically you can also use `BlockOperation`, which is block-based, but for which which you can decouple the creation of the operation, and the adding of the closure to the operation. Using this technique, you can actually pass a reference to the operation to its own closure:

  ```
   private weak var lastOperation: Operation?

   func performSearch(for queryString: String) {
       lastOperation?.cancel()

       let operation = BlockOperation()
       operation.addExecutionBlock { [weak operation, weak self] in
           print("starting \(identifier)")
           for i in 0 ... 10 {
               if operation?.isCancelled ?? true { print("canceled \(identifier)"); return }
               print("  \(identifier): \(i)")
               self?.heavyWork()
           }
           print("finished \(identifier)")
       }
       searchQueue.addOperation(operation)
       lastOperation = operation
   }

   func heavyWork() {
       Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.5)
   }
  ```

  I only mention this for the sake of completeness. I think the `Operation` subclass approach is frequently a better design. I'll use `BlockOperation` for one-off sort of stuff, but as soon as I want more sophisticated cancelation logic, I think the `Operation` subclass approach is better.

I should also mention that, in addition to more elegant cancelation capabilities, `Operation` objects offer all sorts of other sophisticated capabilities (e.g. asynchronously manage queue of tasks that are, themselves, asynchronous; constrain degree of concurrency; etc.). This is all beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: The subclassing approach is a good template. Get it to work in ten Minutes.

Answer (score -1):

you wrote

> Ideally, I'd like to provide the newly-created DispatchWorkItem as an
>   additional parameter

you are wrong, to be able to cancel running task, you need a reference to it, not to the next which is ready to dispatch.

cancel() doesn't cancel running task, it only set internal "isCancel" flag by the thread-safe way, or remove the task from the queue before execution. Once executed, checking isCancel give you a chance to finish the job (early return).

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import Foundation

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
let prq = DispatchQueue(label: "print.queue")
var task: DispatchWorkItem?

func work(task: DispatchWorkItem?) {
    sleep(1)
    var d = Date()
    if task?.isCancelled ?? true {
        prq.async {
            print("cancelled", d)
        }
        return
    }
    sleep(3)
    d = Date()
    prq.async {
        print("finished", d)
    }
}

for _ in 0..<3  {
    task?.cancel()
    let item = DispatchWorkItem {
        work(task: task)
    }
    item.notify(queue: prq) {
        print("done")
    }
    queue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: item)
    task = item
    sleep(1) // comment this line
}
```

in this example, only the very last job is really fully executed

```
cancelled 2018-12-17 23:49:13 +0000
done
cancelled 2018-12-17 23:49:14 +0000
done
finished 2018-12-17 23:49:18 +0000
done
```

try to comment the last line and it prints

```
done
done
finished 2018-12-18 00:07:28 +0000
done
```

the difference is, that first two execution never happened. (were removed from the dispatch queue before execution)