# What are the benefits of using DispatchWorkItem in swift?

Tags: swift, optimization, parallel-processing

Suppose we have the following code defining a continuous loop (as in for a game):

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "DemoSerialQueue")
let workItem = DispatchWorkItem{ print("Hello World") }
func gameLoop() {
  queue.async(execute:workItem)
}
```

Would the above code be more efficient in terms of speed than the following:

```
func gameLoop() {
  queue.async{ print("Hello World") }
}
```

In particular I'm wondering if the second form would be allocating a closure on every loop and thus incuring a performance hit.

Comment: There’s no real benefit to using `DispatchWorkItem` as above. It’s most useful when you need to reference that object associated with that task later (e.g. checking to see if task has canceled, i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38372384/1271826). (That having been said, when you get to sufficient complexity that you want to consider encapsulating blocks of work, then you might also consider [`Operation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation) and [`OperationQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue).)

Comment: By the way, if you want to see other advantages of dispatch work items, see 14:20 into [Concurrent Programming with GCD](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/720/?time=860) WWDC 2016 video.

Comment: So does the second form not allocate a closure on every run of the loop, whereas the first would bypass this?

Comment: Yes, that is the case, though the difference is generally not observable in practical applications...

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The DispatchWorkItem class is an encapsulation of the concept of work item. There are few benefits.

> A dispatch work item has a cancel flag. If it is cancelled before
>   running, the dispatch queue won’t execute it and will skip it. If it
>   is cancelled during its execution, the cancel property return True. In
>   that case, we can abort the execution

By encapsulating our request code in a work item, we can very easily cancel it whenever it's replaced by a new one, like this:

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {
    // We keep track of the pending work item as a property
    private var pendingRequestWorkItem: DispatchWorkItem?

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        // Cancel the currently pending item
        pendingRequestWorkItem?.cancel()

        // Wrap our request in a work item
        let requestWorkItem = DispatchWorkItem { [weak self] in
            self?.resultsLoader.loadResults(forQuery: searchText)
        }

        // Save the new work item and execute it after 250 ms
        pendingRequestWorkItem = requestWorkItem
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(250),
                                      execute: requestWorkItem)
    }
}
```

In general, Dispatch functions can take **a block** or **a DispatchWorkItem** as a parameter. So there won't any performance hit as we use **blocks in both cases**. Use the one that suits you the most.